# Change checkbox + label jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I got multiple *checkboxes and labels* and when the answer is correct I want to change the *background color* of the selected *checkbox and label*

```
<input type="checkbox" id="a" class="check-with-label" />
<label for="a" class="question_box">
    <?php echo $vraag[0]['A'] ?>
</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="b" class="check-with-label" />
<label for="b" class="question_box">
    <?php echo $vraag[0]['B'] ?>
</label>
```

and when the user presses submit it calls an *ajax call* to a script to check if it is the correct answer or not.

```
$('#bottom').on('click', function(){
    $('#antwoorden input:checked').each(function() {
        var selected = $(this).attr('id');
        //var selected_box = this;
        selected = selected.toUpperCase();

        var data = {
            vraag_nummer : <?php echo $vraag[0]['id'] ?>,
            antwoord     : selected
        };

        console.log(data);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url : 'includes/check_correct.php',
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {
                if(data.correct){
                    this.css('background-color', 'green');
                    //selected_box.css('background-color', 'green');
                } else {
                    this.css('background-color', 'red');
                }
            },
            error: function(err) {
                console.log('error');
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

problem is I don't know *how* to call the correct box because when the user presses *submit* the `this` variable is now the submit button and *not* the checked box (There can only be *one* checkbox selected at the time_.

So the question is how do I replace the background color of the selected AND the correct box from

```
.check-with-label:checked + .question_box {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

to

```
background-color:green
```

(and for incorrect `red`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the `label` instead of `this`

You've already got the `ID` of the label

(`var selected = $(this).attr('id');`)

Which will probably return a/b/c/d and then use

`$('label[for="'+selected+'"]').css('background-color', 'green'); //or red in the else statement`

this styles the *label for the selected id, in this case d* 
the code above basicly means:

`$('label][for="d"].css('background-color','green'); //or red`

but then using the chosen variable

Goodluck!

Comment: the id isn't `d` but it is `D` how do I set it to uppercase, I know of the uppercase function but if I do `for="'toUpperCase(d)"` it wont work?

Comment: Try updating the variable `selected= selected.toLowerCase();`

Answer (score 0):

In success use selected_obj.css instead of this.selected and pass $(this) to selected_obj

```
$('#bottom').on('click', function(){
    $('#antwoorden input:checked').each(function() {
        var selected = $(this).attr('id');
        var selected_obj = $(this);
        //var selected_box = this;
        selected = selected.toUpperCase();

        var data = {
            vraag_nummer : <?php echo $vraag[0]['id'] ?>,
            antwoord     : selected
        };

        console.log(data);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url : 'includes/check_correct.php',
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {
                if(data.correct){
                    selected_obj.css('background-color', 'green');
                    //selected_box.css('background-color', 'green');
                } else {
                    selected_obj.css('background-color', 'red');
                }
            },
            error: function(err) {
                console.log('error');
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: It sets the background color on `check-with-label` (which is the checkbox) instead of on the `.check-with-label:checked + .question_box` (which remains orange)

Comment: Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: please upload code on jsfiddle or check in console what you get in selected_obj

Comment: in console it says `[input#b.check-with-label]` like I said in the first comment

Comment: try adding class in success :

if(data.correct) {
 selected_obj.addClass('green');
} else {
selected_obj.addClass('red');
}

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38122596/6359980) worked for me. But thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#bottom').on('click', function(){
    $('#antwoorden .check-with-label').each(function() {
        var selected = $(this).attr('id');
        var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked'));
        if (!isChecked) {
            return;
        }
        var selected_obj = $(this);
        //var selected_box = this;
        selected = selected.toUpperCase();

        var data = {
            vraag_nummer : <?php echo $vraag[0]['id'] ?>,
            antwoord     : selected
        };

        console.log(data);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url : 'includes/check_correct.php',
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {
                if(data.correct){
                    selected_obj.css('background-color', 'green');
                } else {
                    selected_obj.css('background-color', 'red');
                }
            },
            error: function(err) {
                console.log('error');
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Nothing is happening when I put `.bind(this)` at the end of the `succes` function

Answer (score 0):

After the page is rendered and displayed to user, PHP will no longer run. Therefore, in your `$('#bottom').on('click'` function, the PHP code won't work. The trick is to store that information when building the page, such as by writing it into a data attribute or some such.

Inside the AJAX success function the `$(this)` object is not available. Set it to a global variable and you will be able to access the value.

```js
/* javascript/jQuery */
$('#bottom').on('click', function(){
    $('#antwoorden input:checked').each(function() {
        var selected = this.id; //faster, same result
        $this = $(this);
        selected = selected.toUpperCase();

        var data = {
            //change next line - PHP finished running
            vraag_nummer : $this.attr('data-vn'),
            antwoord     : selected
        };

        console.log(data);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url : 'includes/check_correct.php',
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {
                if(data.correct){
                   $this.css('background-color', 'green');
                } else {
                   $this.css('background-color', 'red');
                }
            },
            error: function(err) {
                console.log('error');
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<!-- HTML: -->
<input id="vraag_nummer" data-vn="<?php echo $vraag[0]['id'] ?>" type="text" />
```